# "Disk" always at maximum usage

Tags: windows, performance

I recently opened up my laptop to fix a faulty power connector. Since then I have noticed my disk usage (not sure what it actually corresponds to) has been very high, as in the screenshot below: (Note that the antivirus is not normally running, and the disk usage is the same)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe it corresponds to disk queue length. Can you open resource monitor (start - run "resmon") and take a look? It may give you more insight into what is using your disk. 100% should mean the queue length is 1 or higher. It can be hard to pin down because a high MB/s rate doesn't necessarily correspond to a high disk usage... Random accesses are much harder on  the disk than sequential ones.

Comment: Added an image. At the moment it looks like steam is doing a lot of downloads, but I don't think that would account for it always being at "full"

Comment: @Derongan the queue depth is only shown in the disk tab

Comment: I'll link that in tomorrow morning

Comment: Added. Maybe this is normal behavior and I was just scared off by the disk column in task manager turning red (which always seems to be a bad thing) most of the time. As I type (for once) it is not at a high %, whatever the % actually corresponds to in terms of the disk queue